# JSON.NET Deserialization Issue

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm having trouble deserializing certain data with JSON.NET. The following string, although serialized via JSON.NET, will not deserialize correctly.

> {"ParentClause":null,"FilterClauseType":2,"FilterClauses":[
>   {"FilterClauseType":1,"FilterClauses":[],"ComparisonType":2,"FieldStaticName":"ContentType","Value":"Hidden","FieldValueType":2},
>   {"FilterClauseType":1,"FilterClauses":[],"ComparisonType":1,"FieldStaticName":"ContentType","Value":"Document","FieldValueType":2}],
>   "ComparisonType":null,"FieldStaticName":null,"Value":null,"FieldValueType":null}

Doing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` skips the elements of the `FilterClauses` array, even though they're clearly present. This occurs whether I use the generic or non-generic overload of the method.

Is this a bug, or is there some way to fix this? I tried implementing a custom `JsonConverter`, but the `JReader` passed into that is throwing exceptions.

For reference, this is the class definition:

```
class FilterClause 
{
    public FilterClause ParentClause {get; set;}
    public FilterClauseType FilterClauseType {get; set;}
    public IList<FilterClause> FilterClauses {get; set;}
    public ComparisonType? ComparisonType {get; set;}
    public String FieldStaticName {get; set;}
    public String Value {get; set;}
    public FieldValueType? FieldValueType {get; set;}

    public FilterClause()
    {
        FilterClauses = ImmutableList.Create<FilterClause>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor seems to be creating an ImmutableList. Assuming that instance is in fact immutable, yet still implements IList<FilterClause>, the deserializer is probably calling .Add for every item, which your immutable list class then ignores (since, if it does not, it wouldn't be immutable). Remove the line from your constructor and try again.

Comment: This doesn't matter, as it doesn't work even I when I try to deserialize to an anonymous object (which obviously would not use `ImmutableList`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

**Class Definition**

```
internal class SampleResponse1
{

    [JsonProperty("ParentClause")]
    public object ParentClause { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FilterClauseType")]
    public int FilterClauseType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FilterClauses")]
    public FilterClaus[] FilterClauses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ComparisonType")]
    public object ComparisonType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FieldStaticName")]
    public object FieldStaticName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FieldValueType")]
    public object FieldValueType { get; set; }
}

internal class FilterClaus
{

    [JsonProperty("FilterClauseType")]
    public int FilterClauseType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FilterClauses")]
    public object[] FilterClauses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ComparisonType")]
    public int ComparisonType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FieldStaticName")]
    public string FieldStaticName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("FieldValueType")]
    public int FieldValueType { get; set; }
}
```

**Syntax for Conversion**

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleResponse1>(Your_String);
```